# Gnuplot error with awk in plot command

Tags: gnuplot

I have got the following errors while the using the code.

```
gnuplot> set terminal epslatex size 13.1cm,6cm color colortext
Terminal type set to 'epslatex'
Options are '   leveldefault color colortext \
   dashed dashlength 1.0 linewidth 1.0 butt noclip \
   nobackground \
   palfuncparam 2000,0.003 \
   input size 13.10cm, 6.00cm "" 11  fontscale 1.0 '
gnuplot> set output 'C:\MajCha\gnuplot\alpha_cl.tex'
gnuplot> filename= 'C:\MajCha\gnuplot\DU_08-W-180-65_cf_c_02_InpPrePro.txt'
gnuplot> #
gnuplot> set xrange [-10:10]
gnuplot> set yrange [-3:3]
gnuplot> plot "< awk '$1==-180.0 { print $2, $3 }'" filename using 2:3
         warning: Skipping unreadable file "< awk '$1==-180.0 { print $2, $3 }'"
         No data in plot

gnuplot> #
gnuplot> unset output
gnuplot> reset
```

How could I fix this error.I want the check I made §1=-180 in a loop range from -180 to 180. Please suggest me some possible ways to do.

With using the following code

```
reset
set terminal epslatex size 13.1cm,6cm color colortext
set output 'C:\MajCha\gnuplot\alpha_cl.tex'
filename= 'C:\MajCha\gnuplot\DU_08-W-180-65_cf_c_02_InpPrePro.txt'
#
unset key
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-3:3]
plot for [i=-180:180] filename using (($1==i)?$2:1/0):3 
#
unset output
reset
```

The output figure is 
[image]
With using the following code

```
reset
set terminal epslatex size 13.1cm,6cm color colortext
set output 'C:\MajCha\gnuplot\alpha_cl.tex'
filename= 'C:\MajCha\gnuplot\DU_08-W-180-65_cf_c_02_InpPrePro.txt'
#
unset key
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-3:3]
plot for [i=-180:180] filename using (($1==i)?$2:1/0):3 with lines 
#
unset output
reset
```

the output figure is 
[image]

Comment: You need the following syntax: `plot "<awk '$1==-180.0' filename" using 2:3`. Then it should work. The name of the file should be inside the double quotes. Also, you don't need the `print` statement on awk if you're going to use `using 2:3` on the plotting command.

Comment: It would help if you could show a piece of your data, and be specific about the results you want to get.

Comment: `awk` is a command line tool which is not part of gnuplot, and which you probably don't have available on your Windows system

Comment: My data contains first column ranging from -180 to 180 in steps of 1 for every second column value. I have 21 second column values and the third column has uniques values for all the rows.

Comment: The problem with `lines` is that gnuplot receives the points selected with `($1==i)` as non-contioguous if they're not on successive entries, the data is separated by `1/0` entries. So it will not draw a line from one valid entry to the next. You need to go through an intermeditae file for this, or the `awk` solution also should work. Did you test it with the changes suggested in my answer? You've not edited this part.

Comment: Yes I have tried using "awk" but it is a comment like "awk is not recognised as internal or external command" and it is skipping without plotiing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `filename` is a gnuplot variable in your MWE, what you can do is concatenate its contents to the awk command:

```
plot "<awk '$1==-180.0 { print $2, $3 }' ".filename using 1:2
```

Don't miss out the space character before the closing `"`: this will evaluate the command

```
awk '$1==-180.0 { print $2, $3 }' C:\MajCha\gnuplot\DU_08-W-180-65_cf_c_02_InpPrePro.txt
```

which is I believe what you want to do. Presently, it is evaluating awk with no file at all, thus there is no data.

Note that since your `awk` commands prints only `$2` and `$3`, its output consists of 2 columns, so you probably want `using 1:2` in gnuplot.

Finally, if this MWE is close to what you really want to achieve, I would advise to drop awk and use gnuplot commands only for simplicity:

```
plot filename using (($1==-180)?$2:1/0):3
```

Comment: I have used the following command and it is just plotting titles but no graph
plot for [i=-180:180] filename using (($1==i)?$2:1/0):3 with lines

Comment: That way you'll have 361 plots, all integers i in [-180,180], so unless you use `unset key` you'll see nothing. Then you should post some of your data to understand why if the problem persists.